# Using breadcrumbs with multiple menus for one link

Tags: routes, breadcrumbs

In my website I have 2 menus; the *Main Menu* and the *Header Menu* that I use for *quick links*.

I have 1 page that is linked in both menu.

When I'm on that page, the breadcrumb (and other menu-related blocks) use the hierarchy of the *quick-link* menu.

In my node the menu configured is the *Main Menu* and I added the link manually to the *Header Menu*.

Is there any way to give a *weight* to different modules?

Thanks!

Comment: You could have a look at https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!theme.inc/function/theme_breadcrumb/7

Answer (score 1):

[Multiple Node Menu](https://drupal.org/project/multiple_node_menu) might do the trick:

> This module modifies the "Menu settings" in standard node editing form
>   to allow managing multiple menu links to a node. The Drupal standard
>   behavior is to only care about a single menu link for anode, all other
>   menu links must be added through menu administration.

Answer (score 0):

[Menu Trail by Path](http://drupal.org/project/menu_trail_by_path) *should* help:

> Menu Trail By Path sets the active-trail on menu items according to
>   the current url.

Just in case, I always use [Path Breadcrumbs](http://drupal.org/project/path_breadcrumbs) as well.  If you're comfortable with Page Manager, then the UI is really simple.  If not, then it shouldn't take you long to figure it out :)

> This module is a solution for all problems with the breadcrumbs on
>   your site!
>
> Path breadcrumbs module helps you to create breadcrumbs for any page
>   with any selection rules and load any entity from the URL!

Although if you just want to change the weights of the module in the `system` table, then the following documentation is the place to look: [How to update a module's weight](http://drupal.org/node/110238)

Comment: It DOES work for the Breadcrumb, but I also have a view that check if some pages have a certain parent, which my page should have, but doesn't because of the "quicklink" menu

Answer (score 0):

In [Crumbs](https://drupal.org/project/crumbs) you have one plugin key per menu, which you can prioritize.

E.g. you might have `menu.hierarchy.main-menu` and `menu.hierarchy.header-menu`. Go to admin/structure/crumbs to move them up and down.

Note: You can also use the `menu.hierarchy.*` wildcard.

Crumbs, once enabled, will handle all the breadcrumbs on your site. Usually this is a good thing, but you should evaluate.